# My Webpack configuration for React 18 shows Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "react-dom/client"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am learning webpack to start out my react projects without create-react-app. Everything seems to work fine but when I open the console after `npm run dev`, I see the error message: `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "react-dom/client". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`

[image: The error message in the console]

Below are my project files.

```
webpack-react
├── dist
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── public
│   └── index.html
├── src
│   ├── App.js
│   └── index.js
├── webpack.config.js
└── .babelrc
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Webpack React</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="../src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

App.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Welcome to webpack</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

index.js

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";

const root = document.querySelector("#root");

ReactDOM.createRoot(root).render(<App />);
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    ["@babel/preset-react", { "runtime": "automatic" }]
  ]
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  mode: process.env.NODE_ENV || "development",
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.[hash].js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", "jsx", ".css"],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: {
          loader: "html-loader",
          options: {
            minimize: true,
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: "./public/index.html" }),
  ],
  devServer: {
    host: "localhost",
    port: process.env.PORT || 3000,
    open: true,
  },
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "webpack-react",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server",
    "build": "webpack --mode production --progress"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.17.12",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "html-loader": "^3.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack": "^5.72.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.9.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0"
  }
}
```

I find it weird that react files are rendered despite the message..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the error comes from this line

```
<script type="module" src="../src/index.js"></script>
```

Since you are using Webpack to bundle, the injection is handled by Webpack.
Remove that line, the app should still work and the error should disappear.

Comment: You are a true genius.